Calculation of simulated emission time
In a laser medium, atoms remain in an excited state until they release a photon in a random direction through spontaneous emission. I found here how to calculate the spontaneous emission time. However, if another photon that has the right wavelength interacts with the excited atom before spontaneous emission occurs, it undergoes stimulated emission. I want to know how to calculate the average time it takes for an atom in the laser medium to be hit by another photon and undergo stimulated emission.

If you take the laser intensity in watts and divide by $h\nu$ the result will be the number of atoms per second emitting a photon. Divide by the number of excited atoms and you have the average lifetime. Since the emission is dominated by stimulated emission, the lifetime you get will be the lifetime for stimulated emission.
